# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Mobile not receiving push notification

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Well, i'm trying for the past week to integrate my app with FCM and send a test push notification. I have followed the firebase docs, youtube tutorial videos and nothing works for me... The message is not received and I don't know if there's an error or something like that cuz on the Firebase Console only shows that the campaign was created and is active. I think i'm missing a tiny detail, can someone please help?

So, let me show you my code and configuration.

This is my manifest file:

```
<application> 
<service
    android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@mipmap/finsol_logo_round" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
</application>
```

This is my service:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {



    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {

        sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    }

    private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String?) {

        Firebase.messaging.token
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                Timber.e(task.exception)
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }

            val token = task.result

            Timber.e(token)
        })
    }


    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Timber.e(remoteMessage.messageId)
        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
            generateNotification(remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!, remoteMessage.notification!!.body!!)
        }
    }

    private fun getRemoteView(title: String, message: String): RemoteViews {
        val remoteView = RemoteViews("br.com.finsol.finsolmobile", R.layout.notification)

        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title_notification, title)
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.message_notification, message)
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.logo, R.mipmap.finsol_logo_foreground)

        return remoteView
    }

    private fun generateNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext.applicationContext, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.finsol_logo_foreground)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        builder.setContent(getRemoteView(title, message))

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Well, my dependencies are the exact ones on the firebase docs.

Also, i'm using Android 11.

In the tools > Firebase > Cloud Messaging menu says that the dependencies are set correctly (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMQ5U.png)

Is it possible that it's not working for me because it is a signed app? I also have tried adding Fingerprint SHA-256, even though it is not necessary unless the app is deployed on the store, right?

The app exists in a play console project, does firebase NEEDS to be linked with the same project? Might be it? It seems like the app isn't linked with the firebase at all, even saying it is.

Comment: You need to check whether you getting notification from server first `RemoteMessage` if no then check FCM token whether it's same ,also try firebase console. Use log to debug your code

Answer (score 0):

It can be about `Build.VERSION_CODES`, i will share my working code with you, change yours according to that:

```
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        }
```